# Why drag and drop functionality is not working?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, single-page-application

I aim to fix my code snippet to enable the drag-and-drop functionality for cardElements, allowing them to be dragged and dropped into the payment div using the makeDraggable function.

in the console, it just says "DRAGSTART" so it just running the dragstart I don't know why it's not doing other functions

customerController.js:

```
import {Model} from "../ModelClass.js";
import {api} from "../api.js";
import languageManager from "../languageManager.js";
import {CustomerLeftNavView} from "../views/CustomerLeftNavView.js";
import {MenuView} from "../views/MenuView.js";
import {foodCardBody, foodCardTitle} from "../views/menu/FoodCardDetails.js";
import {beerCardBody, beerCardTitle} from "../views/menu/BeerCardDetails.js";
import {cocktailCardBody, cocktailCardTitle} from "../views/menu/CocktailCardDetails.js";
import {wineCardBody, wineCardTitle} from "../views/menu/WineCardDetails.js";
import {makeDraggable} from "../utils/drag.js";
import {addStyleSheet} from "../utils/styler.js";

class CustomerController {
    constructor() {
    }

    #transformFoodObject(foodObject) {
        return {
            title: foodCardTitle(foodObject),
            body: foodCardBody({ingredientsList: foodObject.ingredients}),
        }
    }

    #transformBeerObject(beerObject) {
        return {
            title: beerCardTitle(beerObject),
            body: beerCardBody(beerObject),
        }
    }

    #transformCocktailObject(cocktailObject) {
        return {
            title: cocktailCardTitle(cocktailObject),
            body: cocktailCardBody({
                description: cocktailObject.description,
                boozeList: cocktailObject.booze,
                servingSize: cocktailObject.servingSize,
                strength: cocktailObject.strength,
            }),
        }
    }

    #transformWineObject(wineObject) {
        return {
            title: wineCardTitle(wineObject),
            body: wineCardBody(wineObject),
        }
    }

    init({leftSection, mainSection, rightSection}) {
        console.log("In customer home controller", {leftSection, mainSection, rightSection});
        addStyleSheet('styles/drag.styles.css');
        // set default data that is being rendered. This loads the whole menu and all the items
        const menuItemsModel = new Model({
            headerTitle: languageManager.getDictionary().menu,
            items: [
                ...api.getTable('food').map(this.#transformFoodObject),
                ...api.getTable('beer').map(this.#transformBeerObject),
                ...api.getTable('cocktails').map(this.#transformCocktailObject),
                ...api.getTable('wine').map(this.#transformWineObject),
            ]
        });

        // render left section
        const leftViewContent = new CustomerLeftNavView(new Model({}), leftSection);
        const leftViewElements = leftViewContent.render();

        // render main section
        const mainSectionView = new MenuView(menuItemsModel, mainSection);
        const cardElements = mainSectionView.render().querySelectorAll('.card');
        cardElements.forEach((card) => {
            makeDraggable(card);
        });
        console.log(cardElements);
        // todo get view for tab in right section
        // const customerTab = new OrderTabView();

        // todo add event listeners for rendering different menus
        const paymentDiv = document.createElement('div');
        paymentDiv.id = 'payment';
        paymentDiv.classList.add('dropzone');
        rightSection.appendChild(paymentDiv);

    }
}

export const getCustomerController = () => new CustomerController();
```

drag.js:

```
export function makeDraggable(element,
                              { // functions that get called after the default drag functions
                                  onDragStart = (event) => {},
                                  onDragOver = (event) => {},
                                  onDrop = (event) => {}
                              } = {},
                              defaultCallbacks = { // these are the default drag functions, they can be overriden with this parameter
                                  // event handlers if not provided
                                  dragstart: (event) => {
                                      event.preventDefault();
                                      console.log('DRAGSTART');
                                      event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'DATATATA');
                                      event.target.classList.add('dragging');
                                      // event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(event.target.cloneNode(true), 0, 0);
                                      onDragStart(event);
                                  },
                                  dragover: (event) => {
                                      event.preventDefault();
                                      console.log('DRAGOVER');
                                      event.target.classList.remove('draggable');
                                      event.target.classList.remove('dragging');
                                      onDragOver(event);
                                  },
                                  drop: (event) => {
                                      event.preventDefault();
                                      console.log("DROPPED");
                                      onDrop(event);
                                  },
                              }) {
    element.setAttribute('draggable', true);
    element.classList.add('draggable');

    for (const event in defaultCallbacks) {
        element.addEventListener(event, defaultCallbacks[event]);
    }

    return element;
}
```